# MYSQL: Error 1064(42000) MariaDB server for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The whole error code says:

Error 1064(42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL'

It's telling me I don't have the right syntax but here is my code what am I missing:

```
 CREATE TABLE CONTACTAPPTABLE
(
MAId int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
MAName varchar(50) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MAEmail varchar(45) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MASMS varchar(15) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MAOpinion text DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MAOtherPaperCompanies varchar(20) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MAStreetAddress varchar(20) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MAColor varchar(20) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MAZipCode varchar(20) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MAMailingType varchar(20) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
MADT timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY(MAId)

)Engine=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1128 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? i see three different in your tags

Comment: If I'm reading the question right I think it's mysql. My teacher told us to use code similar to his and his was written the same way.

Comment: This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b859/1/0) compiles must set values for default values and can't set default on a text data type.

Comment: Please do not link to screengrabs of error messages.  The text of the error message should be included directly in the question.  This is so that others who have this problem another time can benefit from the answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a default value:

```
NOT NULL DEFAULT "abc"
```

[From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

> column_definition:
>       data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]

**edit** in response to xQbert

[According to MariaDB's docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/blob-and-text-data-types/),

> MariaDB starting with 10.2.1
>   BLOB and TEXT columns can now have a DEFAULT value.

If you are running Maria < 10.2.1, you can not use DEFAULT on your *TEXT* data field.

Comment: Also, it appears, you can't set a default on a text data type. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b859/1/0) that compiles. will not w/o removing default on text.

Comment: WilI have to change my syntax as well?

Comment: I do not have a maria instance to test on right now, try it out :D @xQbert see my edit. With Maria 10.2.1, TEXT accepts a default value.

Comment: Looks like it worked. Had to change syntax and set default thank you